# How to match different columns of table in html?

Tags: html

I have a table structure as below:

```
<table>
  <tr id="tr1">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tr2">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tr3">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now it has 2 columns each in first and last row . And 4 columns in 2nd row. Now if i want to add one more column to the last row correspondent to the 4th column in 2nd row , i knw that i should append one empty td to last row and then add that column. But this empty td joining is not possible in all the cases . So how to add columns randomly and manage the structure of table?? Can i get any help??

Comment: do you intend to use javascript/jquery?

Comment: yeah javascript is also fine

Comment: can we use jquery? =)

Comment: yes jquery is also fine

Comment: @Mahan are you serious? Using that big library to change size of column makes no sense, unless he is using jQuery already.

Comment: I am using jquery already

Comment: and jquery is not that big indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you want?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    addCol("tr3", 4);
});

function addCol(rowid, coldes){
    var tr = $("#" + rowid + " td");
    var trctr = tr.length;
    troffset = coldes - trctr;
    alert(troffset);
    for(var i = 1; i <= troffset; i++){
        tr.parent().append("<td></td>");
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/djb78/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. You must merge some cells and remove their borders.
`rowspan` and `colspan` attributes will help

Comment: is it so?very bad... i know abt rowspan and colspan but i cant use that for l0 columns right? no use

Comment: table is for fixed positioning, if you'd like more flexibility, work with div's

Answer (score 0):

Handling HTML tables manually (adding columns etc.) is quite problematic, but there are some libraries for tables / data presentation that may help you.

1. **Datatables**

   http://www.datatables.net/
2. **Flexigrid**

   http://www.flexigrid.info/
3. **SlickGrid**

   https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid
4. **jqGrid**

   http://www.trirand.com/blog/
5. **dgrid and DojoX Data Grids**

   http://dojotoolkit.org/features/desktop.php